# How to not include file extension while reading from Document directory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c-2.0

I am developing an application where i am creating some random .txt file which ultimately stored as a txt file format.

Now for reading these file i am using this code

```
NSString* documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];  
NSError* error = nil;
myArray = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentDirectory error:&error]retain];
```

Now i am displaying the file name in a table view using

```
cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

So it curretly displaying like file1.txt,file2.txt etc.

But i donot want the file extension while displaying in the table list.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cell.textLabel.text = [[myArray objectAtIndex:row] stringByDeletingPathExtension];`

Answer (score 1):

Use `[yourString stringByDeletingPathExtension]` method to remove the extensions from your string. Refer [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) class.